# Amazon Web Services and non-amazon website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm confused about some facets of the Amazon Web Services stuff. Here is what I want to do.

1. My site lets users enter equations and solve them. Some of the equations will deal with large data sets and math that is too computationally expensive for the browser.
2. My site will look at each equation and determine if it should be solved in the browser or on a server.
3. If it needs to be solved on the server, I want to do one of two things. First, either send the data and a function and have AWS run the code on that data. The other option is to have preset code with is given data.
4. AWS then runs the code and returns a JSON of the solution.

For example, lets say that a user has a numeric matrix of 1,000 by 1,000 and they want to take the inverse or do Gaussian elimination. My code would look at the size of the matrix and decide that it needs to be run on the server. The code would then call my function on AWS to solve this, send it the data, and AWS returns the answer.

As I read, I don't understand exactly how to set up EC2 to call a function from a server or from an ajax call. Does AWS not do what I think it does? Do I need to host my site on AWS to do this?

If it matters, I am running a LAMP stack on Hostmonster.

Comment: Your question sounds unclear to me, I think maybe because you don't yet understand enough of what AWS really is to clearly state your problem.  If I'm parsing your thoughts correctly, it sounds like what you really want is a web service (that is hosted on an EC2 instance) that your site can make a request into if it identifies a problem as too computationally complex for the client to handle. Is that correct?

Comment: That is basically what I want, although the problems that I want to solve there aren't necessarily more complex, I just want to crunch small data sets in the browser and large data sets on a server. Is there a section of AWS that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Amazon EC2 to create a server (eg a web server) that is accessible on the Internet. What you load on the server, and how you use the server, is up to you.

There is no functionality provided by Amazon EC2 that would help you for your specific stated use case. Anything you would run on a "normal" server can be run on Amazon EC2, since it is just a virtual machine running an operating system and whatever software you configure.

From your description, you will need to develop a web app that runs mostly in the browser (eg with JavaScript), but also makes calls to a back-end server. How you do that is totally in your control.

Comment: Thanks John. Are you saying that there is no way to develop a web app that makes calls to the AWS back end server?

Comment: You can certainly develop a web app that can call both the AWS API (for managing AWS services) and your own back-end server. What I wanted to convey was that there is no specific service provided by AWS that assists in creating a "backend service for a web app" -- that is all within your responsibility. However, you might want to take advantage of services such as the Simple Queueing Service (SQS) and Amazon Cognito (user identity) as part of your app.